# Create a stored procedure in Firebird from Delphi code

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, firebird

How to create a stored procedure in Firebird from Delphi XE3 code? I want to add a stored procedure through Delphi code. I am using `TSQLQuery.ExecSQL()` but it is throwing an error at line 9 column 10.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_BRANCH_ID (
  EMPID Integer)
 returns (
  EMPBRANCHID Integer)
AS
declare variable EmpBrch Integer;
Begin
 select EMP_BRANCH_ID from EMPLOYEE where EMPLOYEE_ID= :EMPID
   into :EmpBrch;
   EMPBRANCHID = :EmpBrch;
   SUSPEND;
End
```

Delphi code I am using is:

```
with SQLQueryExc do
begin
  close;
  SQL.clear;
  SQL.Add(SPString.Text);
  ExecSQL();
End
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: *it is throwing an error* is not a meaningful problem description unless you tell us **specifically* what error it is *throwing*. What is the **exact** error message you're seeing?

Comment: @Ken White Thanks. It was Token unknown - line 9, column 10? I got the solution by making ParamCheck:=False;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ParamCheck:=False;
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `;` terminates the statement, but you are trying to execute a statement with `;` in it.

You'll need to change the terminator to something else.

```
SET TERM !! ;
CREATE PROCEDURE GET_BRANCH_ID (
  EMPID Integer)
 returns (
  EMPBRANCHID Integer)
AS
declare variable EmpBrch Integer;
Begin
 select EMP_BRANCH_ID from EMPLOYEE where EMPLOYEE_ID= :EMPID
   into :EmpBrch;
   EMPBRANCHID = :EmpBrch;
   SUSPEND;
End !!
SET TERM ; !!
```

Always make sure to change the terminator back to `;` when you're done.

See: http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/isql-terminator.html

Comment: Hi @Johan, Thanks for your help. I got the issue. It was considering the :EmpBrch as parameter. So I made ParamCheck:=False; It worked. Anyway thanks.